# How to know if user disables or deletes work profile in settings?

Tags: android, android-management-api

I am trying to see if device status gets updated when the work profile is *disabled* or *deleted* on client side through Settings. 

After making changes on the client, both disable and deleted, the `status` returned by enterprises.devices.get API is still `ACTIVE`. 

Is there a way to find out there has been a change on the client?

Comment: Still looking for answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way for EMM to detect this other than removing devices that haven't been checked in after a certain period of time.

To achieve this, you can use the [devices.get()](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) method to check on either “lastStatusReportTime” or “lastPolicySyncTime” field on the [Device resource](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices) and see whether the device is communicating to your backend. Then use [devices.delete()](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete) to remove the device.