# MDM Profile Deletion in device

Tags: android-management-api

I have enrolled a device in enterprise .Has anyone have an idea to find whether MDM profile deleted from a device.Is there any option to find it through api?

Answer (score 0):

At this point this is not possible with the Android Management API. Your best bet would be to check the `lastStatusReportTime`  field of the [Device object](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#resource:-device) and assume that a device has been deleted, if the date gets too old. Says 2 weeks, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the devices.list or devices.get doesn’t return the device, you can assume it was factory reset or the work profile was deleted.

This is already answered on this thread. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60594107/how-to-know-if-user-disables-or-deletes-work-profile-in-settings].